# Python client library for Language Server Protocol (LSP)

Tags: python, language-server-protocol

I need to interact with a language server (Eclipse JDT LS) implementing the Language Server Protocol (LSP), and I need it for a Python project that will be used to analyze different programming languages, starting from Java.

I've been looking around for a client library in Python that would fit my purpose, any suggestions?

If it was very easy I wouldn't mind writing one, but I feel the world doesn't need yet another library if a good one exists already.

Comment: A client library is only useful for an editor application, so unless there is a popular code editor written in Python you can expect a well maintained library for you to reuse. However, that doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've discovered that, as of July 2023, there is a library named pygls (https://github.com/openlawlibrary/pygls) that is currently developing a usable client for the Language Server Protocol (LSP).

While we wait for the first official release, I've included it in my setup.py file under "install_requires". This ensures it will be automatically installed during the setup of my project. Here's how I modified the file:

```py
install_requires=[
    'pygls @ git+https://github.com/openlawlibrary/pygls.git'
]
```

With this line of code, pygls will be directly fetched from the GitHub repository and installed into your environment.

Comment: pygls is for building the lsp server and not creating a client that can talk to it.

Answer (score 3):

I am the author of [`multilspy`](https://github.com/microsoft/monitors4codegen#4-multilspy), which is a LSP client in Python, with a library interface and is intended to be used to build applications around language servers. It handles the configuration and initialization of different language servers, and offers a simple interface. It currently supports running [Eclipse JDT.LS for Java](https://github.com/eclipse-jdtls/eclipse.jdt.ls), [rust-analyzer for Rust](https://rust-analyzer.github.io/), [OmniSharp for C#](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn) and [jedi-language-server for Python](https://github.com/pappasam/jedi-language-server). You can install it using pip by running:

```
pip install https://github.com/microsoft/monitors4codegen/archive/main.zip
```

Example usage of `multilspy`:

```
from monitors4codegen.multilspy import SyncLanguageServer
from monitors4codegen.multilspy.multilspy_config import MultilspyConfig
from monitors4codegen.multilspy.multilspy_logger import MultilspyLogger
...
config = MultilspyConfig.from_dict({"code_language": "java"}) # Also supports "python", "rust", "csharp"
logger = MultilspyLogger()
lsp = SyncLanguageServer.create(config, logger, "/abs/path/to/project/root/")
with lsp.start_server():
    result = lsp.request_definition(
        "relative/path/to/code_file.java", # Filename of location where request is being made
        163, # line number of symbol for which request is being made
        4 # column number of symbol for which request is being made
    )
    result2 = lsp.request_completions(
        ...
    )
    result3 = lsp.request_references(
        ...
    )
    ...
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of your research and interestingly enough I needed the LSP integration for a very similar purpose

Comment: That's great! I invite you to checkout our paper https://openreview.net/forum?id=qPUbKxKvXq on improving code generation with language models, especially using the kinds of static anaysis supported by LSPs